# Data Annotations For Validation Generator

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, validation, unobtrusive-validation, data-annotations

Is there any data annotation for validation generator based on SQL Server columns properties, such as maximum string length rather than writing them all over again ?

Edit:

I used scaffolding and it did the work but the data annotations are not comprehensive enough

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the data annotations to be auto created based on the already existing db schema?  Or do you just want to know the annotations for max length?

Comment: I want the data annotations to be auto created based on the already existing db schema !